# laravel pluck corchetes y comillas dobles

Tags: laravel, controller, método, vistas

Tengo la siguiente funcion que muestra el curso de un alumno

```
public function show($id)
{
    $alumno = Alumno::find($id);
    $curso = Matricula::where('id_alumno',$id)->get()->pluck('curso_alumno');
    dd($curso);
    return view('alumnos.show')->with('alumno',$alumno)->with('curso',$curso); 
}
```

EL metodo :

```
public function getCursoAlumnoAttribute()
{
    return $this->curso->nombre. ' - ' . $this->curso->tipo.' / '.$this->curso->created_at->year;
}
```

Pero en mi vista me lo muestra de la siguiente manera:

Curso
["Primero Medio A - Humanista Cientifico / 2017"]

Como puedo eliminar esos corchetes, doble comillas y el "/" duplicado???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No utilices el método `get()` al momento de usar Eloquent, debes aplicar `pluck()` primero y luego `first()` en la colección:

```
$curso = Matricula::where('id_alumno',$id)->pluck('curso_alumno')->first();
```

Una pequeña mejora al código, podrías usar `compact()` al momento de pasar datos a la vista:

```
return view('alumnos.show', compact('alumno', 'curso'));
```

Comment: gracias pero tampoco me funciono, me dice SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'curso_alumno' in 'field list' (SQL: select `curso_alumno` from `matriculas`)

Comment: Los había puesto al revés, por favor prueba ahora.

Comment: Tampoco me funciono, pero lo coloque de esta manera y funciono: $curso = Matricula::where('id_alumno',$id)->get()->pluck('curso_alumno')->first();

Comment: Que curioso, yo hice una prueba real y me funciona sin el get(), pues pluck() es quien toma su lugar y obtiene el resultado de la colección. Lo importante es que pudiste resolver el problema.